how to register and update these params
I am developing an app by react native build by Expo.
I try to register and update some columns, but these don't work well.
My sourcecode is below
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
const URL = {
    CREATE_CURRENT_LOCATION:'https://sayhellotobike-native-ios-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com'
}

export const requestLocationPermission = async (setLocationCallBack,myCurrentLocationArray,setIsMapReady) => {
try {
    const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === 'granted') {
        // 位置情報の取得処理を実行する
        getCurrentLocation(setLocationCallBack,myCurrentLocationArray,setIsMapReady);
        
    } else {
        console.log('Location permission denied');
    }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error requesting location permission:', error);
    }
};

export const getCurrentLocation = async (setLocationCallBack,myCurrentLocationArray,setIsMapReady) => {
    try {
        const { coords } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        const { latitude, longitude } = coords;
        setLocationCallBack({ ...myCurrentLocationArray,latitude, longitude });
        setIsMapReady(true); // マップが準備完了
        writeMyLocationData(URL.CREATE_CURRENT_LOCATION,0,latitude, longitude )
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error getting current location:', error);
        } 
};

import { ref, set } from "firebase/database";
import { database } from '../firebaseConfig'; // Firebaseのデータベースを正しくインポートする必要があります
export const writeMyLocationData = async (url, userId, latitude, longitude) => {
  console.log("書き込み開始:", url, userId, latitude, longitude);
  let params = {
      user_id: userId,
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/3GnaeJSl.png)
    }
  try{
    set(ref(database, url + 'location'), params
  )
  }catch(error){
    console.error(error)
  }finally{
    console.log("処理を送りました。")
  }
  console.log("fetchLocation",fetchLocation)
  // .then(() => {
  //   console.log("書き込み成功:", url, userId, latitude, longitude);
  // })
  // .catch((error) => {
  //   console.error("書き込みエラー:", error);
  // });
}

I guess the path might  be wrong special characters.
Error code is below. I am sure i dont use like.

Error: child failed: path argument was an invalid path = "https:your text//sayhellotobike-native-ios-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/location/latitude". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

I tried to change the path like
/location 
/location/latitude 
location
/

and so on.

I added picture and firebaseconfig.
enter image description here

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"
import { getDatabase }from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCe2ZqMbYldfc-M7hXEBBSNJHnJy5gMig4",
  authDomain: "sayhellotobike-native-ios.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://sayhellotobike-native-ios-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "sayhellotobike-native-ios",
  storageBucket: "sayhellotobike-native-ios.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "94237205998",
  appId: "1:94237205998:web:879feeef3ddb781d3e1aff",
  measurementId: "G-ZLR4NQ9XG4"
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const database = getDatabase(app);


You code doesn't seem to match how Firebase and the Realtime Database are initialized in this quick start guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#web-modular-api How is database exported from firebaseConfig ?

thank you for reply me.
i followed above reference to set up the initialization.
Could you check my config? I ve just posted on answer

Please don't post follow ups as an answer, as that confuses the system. Rather, edit your original post to add the additional information.

The problem you have is that you are using ref(db, path) from the firebase/database package instead of refFromURL(db, url).
On the following line, you incorrectly provide a URL to the ref function when it expects a path.
ref(database, url + 'location')

The reason you get an error is because of the constraint applied to the path variable that blocks the periods (".") in the domain:

Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

To use a URL, you should use refFromURL instead.
refFromURL(database, url + 'location');

However, based on the value of URL.CREATE_CURRENT_LOCATION you need to either use url + '/location' or new URL('location', url).toString() to correctly construct the URL. Currently the URL would be "https://<db>.firebaseio.comlocation" instead of "https://<db>.firebaseio.com/location".
refFromURL(database, url + '/location');


Thank you for your kindly reply.
I tryed to replace to
refFromURL(database, url + '/location',params);
instead of ref(database, url + 'location',params)
Is it possible to use refFromURL member in RealtimeDatabase?


@谷口祐人 params shouldn't be passed into ref. That should be passed into set instead. i.e. set(refFromURL(database, url + '/location'), params). For clarity, you should store the result of refFromURL() as its own variable. i.e. const locationRef = ref(database, url + '/location'); set(locationRef, params)

I hava just solved this problem.
it was trivial mistake...
i didnt have to write a full pass like below...
const path = '/location';
try{
// const locationRef = ref(database, url + '/location');
const locationRef = ref(database, path);;
thanks for your very big kindness
